# Remove middle B from each element in the list

Tags: python-3.x

suppose I have a list which calls name:

name=['ACCBCDB','CCABACB','CAABBCB']

I want to use python to remove  middle B from each element in the list.

the output should display :

['ACCCDB','CCAACB','CAABCB']

Comment: What have you tried? What were the results? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service (though I would gladly charge you the going rate to write this code, and I'll round to the `ceil(hour)`), but we do enjoy helping.

Comment: this is  what I got

Answer (score 0):

def ter(s):

return s[3:-3]

name=['ACBBDBA','CCABACB','CABBCBB']

xx=[ter(s) for s in name]

z=xx

print(z)

output

> > > ['B', 'B', 'B']

I did the reverse I want to delete B in middle and keep the other parts from each element

Answer (score 0):

```
name = ['ACCBCDB','CCABACB','CAABBCB']
name_without_middle = []

for oldstr in name:
  midlen = int((len(oldstr)/2))
  newstr = oldstr[:midlen] + oldstr[midlen+1:]
  name_without_middle.append(newstr)

print(name_without_middle)
```

Returns

**['ACCCDB', 'CCAACB', 'CAABCB']**

Try it [here](https://repl.it/E5nF/0)

Comment: please mark as correct answer by clicking the green arrow :)